# CSS - градиент на background

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, градиент

Есть рабочий код:

```
background:url('/wp-content/images/flag.png') #c6e3fe 7% 10px no-repeat;
```

Но я захотел всунуть градиент в это дело:

```
background:url('/wp-content/images/flag.png') linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#c6e3fe 100%) 7% 10px no-repeat;
```

И конструкция перестала работать.
Есть ли возможность всунуть в эту конструкцию градиент?
[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w29rLzuy/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поставьте запятую и все будет работать.

```
background:url('/wp-content/images/flag.png'), linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#c6e3fe 100%) 7% 10px no-repeat
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо! И ещё надо поменять местами значения: `background:url('/wp-content/images/flag.png') 7% 10px no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#c6e3fe 100%);`

Comment: @I_CaR , верно!)